# How do I multiply two matrices mod2?

Tags: matrix, modular-arithmetic

I have two matrices $A$ and $B$ which I multiply to give

$$\begin{bmatrix}
2 \\
2 \\
2
\end{bmatrix}$$

How do I multiply these matrices Modulo 2? I would like to end up with an all zero column vector.

Comment: Mod[{2, 2, 2}, 2] ?

Comment: Why not `Mod[A.B, 2]`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I assume that by multiplication you mean the dot product. The following should work:

```
Inner[Mod[Times[##], 2] &, A, B, Mod[Plus[##], 2] &]
```

Or, as a function:

```
DotModulo[a_, b_, mod_] := Inner[Mod[Times[##], mod] &, a, b, Mod[Plus[##], mod] &]

DotModulo[A, B, 2]
```

Comment: I do not think your algorithm achieves the theoretical $\mathcal{O}(n^2)$ scaling.

Comment: No, you'd need a dedicated, low-level implementation for that. But I doubt that really matters for most users.